# PCI device: who assign I/O address range ? (Bios, Driver or Opeating System)

Tags: device-manager, io, input-device

Who assign I/O memory adress range ?

[image]

I'm a little confused, I don't know if this address range is assigned by Bios, Driver or Operating system.
I have a problem with an address range of a device and I have to limit the scope of my investigation.
I/O problem is described bellow (see big wrong I/O range) :

[image]

Important informations :
The device does not work and devicemanager show the following error : *This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system.* I disale 90% of the other devices but i have the same error.

- **PCI Card** : [PCI334A](https://www.sunhillo.com/product/pci334a/)
- **Operating system** : Windows server 2008R2 (in old and new machine)
- **Motherboard** : [ASMB-784](https://www.advantech.com/products/serverboard/asmb-784/mod_e491b69c-cd9c-4d54-af5e-0c251cb104b5)
- **CPU** : LGA 1150 Intel® Xeon® E3-1200 v3 and 4th Generation Core i7/i5/i3 processors

Comment: You don't adjust address ranges manually unless and until you know what you're dealing with. This is managed by the system and it has been several decades since PCs have required their owner to manage memory directly. I suggest that instead of asking this question, you ask the question you allude to in the last line of your post.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks. you say : This is managed. What do you understend by "system" ? BIOS, Driver or Operating system ?

Comment: Yes. The answer is "yes". Plug and Play manages memory assigned to devices automatically and is a collaboration between BIOS, OS, and driver.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks. And for PCI device wich is not a plug and play ? who assign this memory adress range ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having that requires you to change this address?

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks. I edit the post to see error. On an old machine all works fine and I have only one I/O adress range, on this new machine, i have two I/O adress ranges and the second are verry big and totaly wrong. I don't know if i must investigate from Bios side, Driver side or Operating system side. Drivers are up to date, Windows also (I install All KB)

Comment: What is the device? What OS are you running this on? What are the basic specs of the CPU and mainboard? Is the device just not working, are you getting error messages? Do you know the device is functional?

Comment: @music2myear I update the post by adding all requested details.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if this address range is assigned by Bios, Driver or Operating system.

Either by the BIOS, or by the OS. A well-designed OS shouldn't require a device driver to do this (though I suppose it can't prevent them from doing it).

This is done by the **configuration space** of a PCI device, which defines sizes for all **base address registers** (BARs). Either the BIOS or the OS (or both) go through those and can change the assignment.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space):

> To address a PCI device, it must be enabled by being mapped into the system's I/O port address space or memory-mapped address space. The system's firmware, device drivers or the operating system program the Base Address Registers (commonly called BARs) to inform the device of its address mapping by writing configuration commands to the PCI controller. Because all PCI devices are in an inactive state upon system reset, they will have no addresses assigned to them by which the operating system or device drivers can communicate with them. Either the BIOS or the operating system geographically addresses the PCI slots (for example, the first PCI slot, the second PCI slot, or the third PCI slot, etc., on the motherboard) through the PCI controller using the per slot IDSEL (Initialization Device Select) signals.
>
> Since there is no direct method for the BIOS or operating system to determine which PCI slots have devices installed (nor to determine which functions the device implements) the PCI bus(es) must be enumerated. Bus enumeration is performed by attempting to read the vendor ID and device ID (VID/DID) register for each combination of bus number and device number at the device's function #0.
>
> [...]
>
> When a read to a specified B/D/F combination for the vendor ID register succeeds, a device driver knows that it exists; it writes all ones to its BARs and reads back the device's requested memory size in an encoded form. The design implies that all address space sizes are a power of two and are naturally aligned.[1]
>
> At this point, the BIOS or operating system will program the memory-mapped and I/O port addresses into the device's BAR configuration register. These addresses stay valid as long as the system remains turned on. Upon power-off, all these settings are lost and the procedure is repeated next time the system is powered back on.

For your actual problem:

> "This device cannot find enough free resources that it can use. If you want to use this device, you will need to disable one of the other devices on this system."

this is impossible to answer unless one looks at the complete assignment of all devices in your system. Also, some devices have restrictions on where the BARs should end up.

Your particular I/O range at `4200FFFF` looks extremely fishy, so my guess is that this is malfunctioning hardware where some of the BAR bits are stuck, so it gets assigned an I/O range that's just not available on your machine.

If this is the case, you can disable other devices until you are green in the face, and nothing will change. The only way to fix this is either fix or replace the hardware, and fixing is really difficult even if you have the equipment to desolder and replace chips.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to modify the Bars registry content ? I need to delete this second I/O range wich is wrong

Comment: Yes, it's possible, e.g. with `setpci` under Linux. I don't know how to do it under Windows. But if the hardware is faulty, this won't help.

Comment: Thanks. I found the equivalent of "setpci" in Windows, if I set the wrong I/O range, Disable and Enable Device, you think it will work ?

Comment: No, I don't think it will work - after all, you have no idea why it ended up in the range where it is, and you also have no idea what this I/o range, and how the driver uses it. But feel to try.

Comment: Please, do you know the LINUX command (as I found Windows setpci equivalent command) to set an I/O range ? my Vendor ID is `15AD` and my device ID is 0405. Actually i can just execute this command : `setpci -d 15AD:0405 device_id` but i don't know how to add argument to modify my I/O range. To symplify, i want just to put `0000` in my wrong I/O range. Thanks.

Comment: Read up on the PCI config space (google), where the BAR registers are (it's different for every card, there's a kind of linked list). Dump config space for your device, find hex address for the BAR register in question, write hex values to this address. If you make a mistake, interesting things could happen.